# How to model Convolutional recurrent network ( CRNN ) in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to port [CRNN](https://github.com/meijieru/crnn.pytorch/blob/master/models/crnn.py) model to Keras.

But, I got stuck while connecting output of Conv2D layer to LSTM layer.

Output from CNN layer will have a shape of **( batch_size, 512, 1, width_dash)** where first one depends on batch_size, and last one depends on input width of input ( this model can accept variable width input )

For eg: an input with shape **[2, 1, 32, 829]** was resulting output with shape of **(2, 512, 1, 208)**

Now, as per [Pytorch model](https://github.com/meijieru/crnn.pytorch/blob/ab61ff13c204a03d08b2836f39688c851f50fb12/models/crnn.py#L73), we have to do **squeeze(2)**  followed by **permute(2, 0, 1)** 
it will result a tensor with shape [208, 2, 512 ]

I was trying to implement this is Keras, but I was not able to do that because, in Keras we can not alter batch_size dimension in a **keras.models.Sequential** model

Can someone please guide me how to port above part of this model to Keras?

[Current state of ported CNN layer](https://hastebin.com/uceyovenin.md)

Comment: Update: [Successfully ported](https://github.com/harish2704/pottan-ocr/tree/pre-alpha/web-demo)  Pytorch model into Keras and I was able to run a trained model inside Web browser using Keras-js .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to permute the batch axis in Keras. In a pytorch model you need to do it because a pytorch LSTM expects an input shape `(seq_len, batch, input_size)`. However in Keras, the `LSTM` layer expects `(batch, seq_len, input_size)`.

So after defining the CNN and squeezing out axis 2, you just need to permute the last two axes. As a simple example (in `'channels_first'` Keras image format),

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(512, 3, strides=(32, 4), padding='same', input_shape=(1, 32, None)))
model.add(Reshape((512, -1)))
model.add(Permute((2, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

You can verify the shapes with `model.summary()`:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 1, None)      5120
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_3 (Reshape)          (None, 512, None)         0
_________________________________________________________________
permute_4 (Permute)          (None, None, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                69760
=================================================================
Total params: 74,880
Trainable params: 74,880
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361376/converting-state-parameters-of-pytorch-lstm-to-keras-lstm)

Comment: what if the input_shape was (1, 3, 28) with meaning (channels, timestep, features), so the output of the convolutions would be (512, channels, 3, 28)?